# Printer does not work after changing OS to Ubuntu

Tags: printing

I changed OS from Windows 7 to Ubuntu.  All is fine, but my printer will not print.  Settings indicate it is linked. Screen even shows it is transferring data, but no page is produced.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: What printer do you have and what steps dit you take setting it up?

Comment: printer, make and model please. How was it installed? Did you manually install it by selecting a protocol?